# $(MAKEFLAGS) behaviour with simply expanded variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I cannot understand the behavior of `$(MAKEFLAGS)` variable. To explain what I want to say, I wrote a very simple makefile:

```
$(info *** $(MAKEFLAGS))
STRING := $(MAKEFLAGS)
all:
    echo MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    echo STRING=$(STRING)
```

running make in a command line with some variables:

```
$ make DEBUG=1 INST=/tmp
*** 
echo MAKEFLAGS= -- INST=/tmp DEBUG=1
MAKEFLAGS= -- INST=/tmp DEBUG=1
echo STRING=
STRING=
```

I wonder how can I assign the `$(MAKEFLAGS)` to a simply expanded variable (with the `:=`) and why I cannot see its value with `$(info ...)`

Comment: If you are unsure about the output of `$(info)` put some separators around the variable contents, e.g. `$(info <$(MAKEFLAGS)>)`. This way you can tell whether there are spaces, something or nothing inside the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how can I assign the $(MAKEFLAGS) to a simply expanded variable (with the :=)

And why not? Roughly saying, "simple assignment" means that the value of the right-hand-side will be expanded in-place until no more `$` are found. So you can assign pretty much anything to a "simple" variable.

> why I cannot see its value with $(info ...)

You *do see* it, it's empty. At least, it's empty while preprocessing the "body" of a makefile (and this is also why `STRING` is always empty - it's a value of `MAKEFLAGS` on the line #2), though it's not empty while expanding the recipe. Well, it's a special variable after all.

Comment: Saying: It's not working as expected because it is special, is not helpful! Some hints to the reasoning why it is populated only within the recipe or a pointer to some documentation would be nice. I couldn't find any.

Comment: @morty Make is a very old program, and reasoning "why" is a bit pointless. Concerning docs, just read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html) carefully: _This variable is set up automatically by make to contain **the flag letters** that make received_.

Comment: Yes, but is does not say that, or even why, it gets populated only at the recipe stage.